# Source on save R file in Eclipse StatET

Tags: r, eclipse, rstudio

I'm starting learning R with coursera.org. I've chosen Eclipse Java Neon with StatET plugin as editor and here is my question. Is any more efficient way to loading file to R console instead writing source("file.R") after every change in this file? I mean about something like "Source on save" in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

## Running R documents

1. What I use the most is simply selecting in the window the part I want to run and run

`Ctrl+R Ctrl+R`

if I want to run the whole file

`CtrlA+ Ctrl+R Ctrl+R`

2. if I want to run the R script by submitting directly

`Crtl R + Ctrl D`

or

right click in the document, run as
[image: run as]

If I want to save the file first `Ctrl+S`

3. you can also use the buttons in the toolbar at the top, they will let you learn the shortcuts.
   [image]

If you prefer different shortcuts. 
`Window>Preference>General>Keys` and edit the shortcuts you want to have.